# SLAM for octomap mapping

Tags: ros, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a 3D map with hector_quadrotor using octomap_mapping. Should I be running a SLAM in the background like the hector_slam to generate a octomap?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218087/slam-for-octomap-mapping/) by [boon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21540/boon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, octomap is purely a mapping approach, so the robot has to be localized via some other approach. Of course, the quality of your octomap is directly coupled to the performance of the used SLAM approach.

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgNFeDH3qFk) we use hector_mapping for localization (and 2D mapping) using a Hokuyo UTM-30LX LIDAR. Simultaneously, a octomap is generated via a Asus Xtion Pro Live sensor mounted on the robot (the colored points visible in rviz show the octomap).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boon](https://answers.ros.org/users/21540/boon/) on 2015-09-24**:
I am just simulating as I run the indoor_ slam_gazebo  available with hector_quadrotor_`demo package by adding a kinect sensor to the quadrotor for localization .Now will running a octomap_server, like,

'rosrun octomap_server octomap_server_node'

generate the octomap? should rtabmap be used too?

**Comment by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on 2016-01-13**:
hi stefan, as you have mentioned that you used hokuyo lidar to 2D map the environment using the hector_slam algorithm and then you have generated the octomap, my question is how have you combined the both results as shown in the video

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-03-24**:
I believe the way it works is that hector_mapping provides the transform between the /map and /odom frames, which then link all of the other parts. Octomap builds the map based on the /map frame, so as long as the transforms are right the 3D map should be built on the 2D occupancy grid.